# Что может находиться в render кроме return?

Tags: reactjs

Просматривая разные примеры вижу, что часто люди в render() хранят логику компонента: частично или полностью. Допустим у нас есть дефолтный компонент:

```
export default class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
     ...
  };
     ...
  render() {
     ...
    return (
      <div>
        {app}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Какая логика может храниться в render()? Насколько она может быть сложной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не советую что нибудь там хранить.

> Книга **React в действии** стр. 60 пункт 2.2.5 Метод рендеринга

Второй абзац:

Метод `render` должен возвращать только один элемент React.

Внимание на ключевое слово **должен**.Метод `render` всегда должен быть и оставаться чистой.Плохая практика делать там сайд эффекты либо вызывать `setState`.(Во втором случае либо ваш код попадет в бесконечный цикл  либо покажет вот такое предупреждения

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). 
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

Что также говорит о том что метод `render` должен быть чистой функцией.

Также в render нельзя получить доступ к UI элементам.

```
render() {
  // Вот так делать вообще не стоит
  const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(nodeElement);
```

Получите ошибку:

```
Warning: Person is accessing getDOMNode or findDOMNode inside its render(). 
render() should be a pure function of props and state
```

Логика которая можно использовать в `render` по моему опыту это условный рендеринг.

```
render(){
  if(this.state.viewMode === "night"){
     return <Night />
  } else {
     return <Day />
  }
}
```

Хотя и эту логику в идеале нужно выносить в отдельную функцию и вызывать внутри `return`

```
renderMode() {
    if(this.state.viewMode === "night"){
         return <Night />
    } else {
         return <Day />
    }
}

render(){
   return (
       <>
          <h3>Hi there</h3>
          {this.renderMode()}
       </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Отлично! То что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @CryNet пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Логика влияющая на "содержимое" возвращаемое return
Обычно в render получают значения state, обрабатывают их так, чтобы использовать в "содержимом" возвращаемым return
Можно также использовать конструкцию с несколькими return

```
if(this.state.loaded) {
  return 
    <div>
      {app}
    </div>
} else {
 return 
    <div>
      Loading
    </div>
}
```